# How to get_the_term_list() from multiple taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have two custom taxonomies: 'cities', & 'policy'. I'd like to display all the terms from each taxonomy at the bottom of a post, with links. This is what I would use for a single taxonomy - let's say cities:

`echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'cities', '', ' / ', '' );`

But I want the list to include terms in cities and terms in policy.

Comment: There are the [`term_links-<taxonomy>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/term_links-taxonomy/) and [`the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_terms/) filter hooks, but how about just call the function once for each the taxonomies.. so `echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'policy', '', ' / ', '' );` for the `policy` taxonomy.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks. That's what I'm doing now. I need to figure out how to output the divider " / " so that it only appears if both get_the_term_lists return something: ```<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'cities', '', ' / ', '' ); ?> / <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'policy', '', ' / ', '' ); ?>```

Comment: You can put them in an array, e.g. `$lists = [ get_the_term_list( ... ), get_the_term_list( ... ) ];`, then join them using your divider: `echo implode( ' / ', array_filter( $lists ) );`. Alternatively, you can use [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) to get the terms in your taxonomies, then manually loop through the array items and echo a link for each term. Just remember that, `wp_get_post_terms()` does not cache the results, so `get_the_terms()` is preferred when looping over a posts query result.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, array('cities','policy'));

or
wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, array('cities','policy'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I stuck with [sally-cj](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/137402/sally-cj)'s suggestion of doing two separate queries.  My challenge was how to make the separator work. Using the separator between the two lists resulted in a phantom separator if either list (or both) returned nothing. So I ended up storing the results of each query in a variable and joining them:

```
    $city_terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'cities', '', ' / ', '' );
    $policy_terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'policy', '', ' / ', '' );
    echo $city_terms;
    if ($city_terms && $policy_terms) {
        echo ' / ';
    }
    echo $policy_terms;
```